# How to parse CSV files in Python?

Tags: python, csv, import-from-csv

I have downloaded the billing reports from AWS, which are in CSV format, onto my server.

Now, I have to parse those CSV files in Python so that it shows consolidated/individual cost information on day/week/monthly basis.

Can anyone please help me with this?

```
import csv 
with open('588399947422-aws-billing-detailed-line-items-2015-09.c‌​sv') as csvfile: 
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile,delimiter=',') 
    for row in readCSV : 
        print row
```

CSV headers

```
"InvoiceID","PayerAccountId","LinkedAccountId","RecordType",‌​"RecordId","ProductN‌​ame","RateId","Subsc‌​riptionId","PricingP‌​lanId","UsageType","‌​Operation","Availabi‌​lityZone","ReservedI‌​nstance","ItemDescri‌​ption","UsageStartDa‌​te","UsageEndDate","‌​UsageQuantity","Blen‌​dedRate","BlendedCos‌​t","UnBlendedRate","‌​UnBlendedCost","Reso‌​urceId","user:Applic‌​ation Name","user:Business Unit"
```

Comment: Please show us the code u have tried

Comment: Use pandas for csv [pandas read csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html)

Comment: import csv
with open('588399947422-aws-billing-detailed-line-items-2015-09.csv') as csvfile:
   readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile,delimiter=',')
   for row in readCSV :
     print row
I don't know how to display cost info on day/week/monthly basis

Answer (score 1):

Use built-in `csv` module.

From docs:

```
>>> import csv
>>> with open(path_to_your_file, 'rb') as csvfile:
...     reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='|')
...     for row in reader: # iterate over reader line by line (line is a list of values in this case)
...         print row # list of values
```

First, you have to open `csv`, the best option is to use `with open(filename,'rb') as f:`.

Then, instantiate `reader` - you have to specify delimiter (comma in most cases) and quotechar (quotes if there are some).

Then you can iterate over reader line by line.

Comment: How is that going to display cost information on day/week/monthly basis?? This code will just read my csv file.

Comment: You didn't attached form of your csv, format of your csv, headers etc. How we could know what is cost on daily bases? Rewrite your question.

Comment: "InvoiceID","PayerAccountId","LinkedAccountId","RecordType","RecordId","ProductName","RateId","SubscriptionId","PricingPlanId","UsageType","Operation","AvailabilityZone","ReservedInstance","ItemDescription","UsageStartDate","UsageEndDate","UsageQuantity","BlendedRate","BlendedCost","UnBlendedRate","UnBlendedCost","ResourceId","user:Application Name","user:Business Unit"

Comment: These are the headers of my csv file. So, I need to parse it so that it'll be able to give me billing info on daily or weekly or monthly basis

Comment: @Ashima I think this is more of a data specific question rather than a code specific one. I doubt if we ll be able to do something without knowing the nature of the data as this is more specific to your requirement.